# Error with octomap and hector_indoor_slam

Tags: ros, octomap-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run octomap_server along with hector_indoor_slam. But when I try to map, I get an error with octomap as follows,

```
[ERROR] [1442979646.410189416, 1543.345000000]: Client [/rviz] wants topic /octomap_point_cloud_centers to have datatype/md5sum [nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid/3381f2d731d4076ec5c71b0759edbe4e], but our version has [sensor_msgs/PointCloud2/1158d486dd51d683ce2f1be655c3c181]. Dropping connection.

[ERROR] [1442979677.062076900, 1550.629000000]: Client [/rviz] wants topic /octomap_full to have datatype/md5sum [nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid/3381f2d731d4076ec5c71b0759edbe4e], but our version has [octomap_msgs/Octomap/9a45536b45c5e409cd49f04bb2d9999f]. Dropping connection.
```

why does the error occur?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218088/error-with-octomap-and-hector_indoor_slam/) by [boon](https://answers.ros.org/users/21540/boon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2015-09-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error message indicates there is a mismatch of message types between the publisher and subscriber sides. It looks like you accidentally tried using a "OccupancyGrid" display for the  `/octomap_point_cloud_centers`topic. This is wrong however, you should be using a "PointCloud2" display for that topic.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0